# Conditional dependence/ independence

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In which of the situations are A and B independent if A is performed first?

1. A = Pick a card from a pile, put it back B = Pick a card from the
   same pile
2. A = Pick two cards from the pile, put one back and keep one B = Pick
   one card from the pile
3. A = Pick one card from the pile and keep it B = Pick one card from
   another pile and keep it

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: What are your thoughts? It isn't difficult to know the answer to this intuitively without even bringing probabilities into it.

Comment: My toughts are: first and last are independent

Comment: Ok. Now consider a pile with 2 cards labelled A and B. For (1), you pick a card and replace it. Now you have to pick a card from the same pile. Have the possible outcomes of what this card could be been affected by what you just did? Or is it the same as if we didn't pick up a card first? Now repeat this thought process for (2) and (3). Does this change one of your thoughts? (Hint: It should) You can formalise this by computing $P(\text{first card is A})P(\text{second card is A})$ and seeing if it is the same as $P(\text{first card A, second card A})$. If it is, then they are indep. Else not.

Comment: In case $1$, do you replace the first card in a uniformly chosen random position in the pack?  And are the cards selected unifromly at random?

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, $A$ and $B$ are independent. Whether or not I pick up a card from the pile and put it back has no effect on the available cards to pick from for $B$.

In the second scenario, $A$ and $B$ are dependent. Depending on which card I keep in $A$, the choices for $B$ change. So the outcome of $B$ depends on what card I picked in $A$.

In the final scenario, $A$ and $B$ are independent again. No matter which card i pick from the first pile for $A$, it does not affect the cards in the second pile for $B$ so the possible outcomes for $B$ are unchanged and therefore do not depend on $A$.